# load select table columns dynamically c# mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a database with multiple columns as "Transactions" table with columns A, B, C, D, E, etc..

i am currently loading entire table using

```
var transactions = db.Transactions.where().ToList() ...... (db is a data context)
```

Now, depending on the user's form submission, I want to select columns A or B or C or any one of their combinations dynamically.

however, using

```
transactions.AsQueryable().Select( q => new { (searchResult.A ? q.A : q.id), (searchResult.B ? q.B : q.id) });
```

(searchResult is a model object returned from a form which has checkboxes for all the column names of Transactions table)

shows error

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name of member access.

anything i'm missing or should do differently?

Comment: In any approach the result will always be a `dynamic` because the result type is not known at compile time. The question is whether you can process these `dynamic`s in code afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add names to your anonymous type, like:

```
transactions.AsQueryable().Select( q => new { A = (searchResult.A ? q.A : q.id), B = (searchResult.B ? q.B : q.id) });
```

P.S. This should work if `A`, `B`, and `id` columns have the same DB type

Comment: Thanks @MaxBrodin, your solution solved the errors.

However, I am actually creating charts from data stored in db. The program calculates values for all of the variables (40+!!). The user then selects which variables s/he wants to display in the chart using checkboxes.

I therefore want to select only the variables/columns that the user has selected and forward the loaded data to JS library.

For e.g. the user might only want to see the data for column A and C in the chart while discarding B, D, E, etc.. from the table. How would i go about creating such data?

Comment: @user2846090 You can use [Database.SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx)
or [Build dynamic expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx)
or [Raw sql query](http://anexinetmobility.blogspot.com/2013/09/returning-dynamic-data-with-entity.html)